# Change color scheme for inactive list selection in LibreOffice on Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, kde, themes, libreoffice, colors

To illustrate the problem, I use LibreOffice Writer as an example, although similar thing happens in other LibreOffice applications too. I'm not sure if this problem is isolated to LibreOffice only.

Here is a screenshot with the text cursor located on the document title. In the adjacent styles panel (highlighted with red outline in image below), the correct style is automatically selected from the list, but its color scheme is illegible.

[image]

If I click on the style panel itself, however, the selection color changes and becomes readable:

[image]

A similar thing happens with the top menu bar (but harder to capture a screenshot of this) - the menu items in the bar are legible until I click on one to get a drop-down menu, at which point the text in the dropdown is legible, but the text for that item in the menubar turns to grey on grey.

**What I've tried:**

1. I've tried changing kde color scheme (currently set to Breeze). Does not help
2. Changing "Inactive selection changes color" in KDE Color Scheme Options does not help
3. Changing "Selection Inactive Text" color in KDE color scheme does not help
4. Updating LibreOffice to latest ppa version (5.3.3) does not help
5. I can't find any settings in the LibreOffice color configuration menu that  are relevant. They only seem to change how text in the document looks, but don't affect the UI itself.

I'm using Kubuntu 17.04, Plasma 5.9.4, LibreOffice 5.3.3

Comment: Thanks @DKBose I found that I also had to remove package `libreoffice-kde` to get this to work.